# Random maps in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to assign a "random" factor to my materials. I want to load 5 different diffuse maps in my material and assign the same material to 300 objects. The "random node" should take any one of the loades maps and assign it to a object.

Is this or any similar operation possible? Or is it possible to "shift" the uv coordinates randomly to another place in one texture, or to mix the original map with a color (randomly choosen?).

Answer (score 15):

If you want to shift the UV maps around you could use the random output from the *Object Info* node to give each texture a random location.

[image: object info node]

My simple node layout:
[image: randomize texture layout]

Comment: thank you! the object info node was the needed hint!- lots more on http://blendersushi.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/cycles-object-info-node.html

Comment: @Rosebarb be sure to accept an answer, if it effectively answered your question... ratings are the life blood on stack exchange websites... im sure that if there was a "thuglife.stackexchange.com" you would get shot for that check mark lol =)

Comment: You can also plug the random into a mix node in order to pick a random one of your five diffuse maps.