# How can I randomize a value for a node?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

How can I randomize a numerical value for a node? Is there any one node, or combination of nodes that can achieve this effect?

Comment: Yup, Sambler mentioned that below. Did you ever get that answer to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Object Info Node's Random Output**

I just discovered there is an Input node that can output a random value:
  Input -> Object Info
However, it only works for Material Shader nodes.

Here is the [Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Object_Info) description of this node:

> **Object Info**
>   Information about the object instance. This can be useful
>   to give some variation to a single material assigned to multiple
>   instances, either manually controlled through the object index, based
>   on the object location, or randomized for each instance. For example a
>   Noise texture can give random colors or a Color ramp can give a range
>   of colors to be randomly picked from.
>
> Note that this node only works for material shading nodes; it does
>   nothing for lamp and world shading nodes.
>
> **Location:** Location of the object in world space.
>   **Object:** Index Object pass index, same as in the Object Index pass.transformed.
>   **Material Index:** Material pass index, same as in the Material Index pass.
>   **Random:** Random number unique to a single object instance.

Comment: That is only for shader nodes, right?

Comment: Yes, Greg, you're right.

Comment: [Duplicate of this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5393/is-it-possible-to-get-a-random-number-in-the-node-editor). My answer of using a driven value node is also available within composite nodes.

Comment: Sambler, thanks for the tip. That is exactly what I was looking for, but I have no experience coding. Do you have any suggestions on beginning tutorials for implementing your suggestion?

Comment: Sambler, can that technique be turned into a script to make a Random Value node? I know how to get a script for a node into Blender. That would be SO awesome!

Comment: Actually Sambler, I got it to work! Thanks! I just put #noise.random() in for the value...I hadn't realized you can do that.

Comment: Wait a second, I did NOT get it to work. When I add a Value node into a blank Compositor screen and set it's value to #noise.random(), after I click away, the value changes every time I move the node or move the mouse over the node. BUT, when I add the node to an existing node tree & enter #noise.random(), the value stays set to a fixed number and doesn't change, even though the field stays purple (indicating it's a calculated value I assume). Why doesn't it continue to be random when other nodes are present?