# Limit object info node random behaviour?

Tags: texturing, materials, objects, node-editor

I ran into a problem with the random node, I'm hoping I can find an answer too.
Does any body know if it is possible to have the "object info> random" node not effect stacks of objects? so it would only give a random value to objects with different X & Y positions, but not randomize the value objects stacked in Z?

Or maybe I could group the object stacks and is there some way the random node could effect objects by group rather then mesh?

I'm including a image of a simplified version of the problem I'm having.
[image: random color example]
I would like the Random node to give each tower a random value, but I want the value to be the same for all the vertical objects up the tower. so ideally I want this to be 3 towers, of 3 blocks, and each tower should be the same value for all 3 of its blocks, but each tower would have a different value from the other.

Here is the hard part, I need the random value to come from the random node, not the Position or Location node (although its fine if either of those are used to help limit the random node), and I can't combine all the blocks of a tower, as the center blocks have array modifiers giving them their height.

Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: hmm, with all the qualifications in the last paragraph, I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: I think what you really need is a random number generator that depends on the object's x and y, but not on z. See this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5393/is-it-possible-to-get-a-random-number-in-the-node-editor

Comment: Or this (both links are only for ideas): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33780/can-i-get-a-new-random-number-per-ray-in-the-node-editor