# How to have the texture of a circle separated in bands each with a different factor (or color) in a shader?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, procedural, mathematics

I created a simple shader to subdivide a circle in a specified number of bands. Each bands has a number between 0 and 1 and the factor (color) for each band is (previous bands + 1/NumberOfBands); I would like to know if there is a way to obtain a random number for each band ( between 0 and 1 possibly ) i.e. a number not related to the previous (or the following) band.

It would be perfect a node that output a random number with a seed option, and I can plug the color in the seed, any one know if there is an addon for that?

[image: bands]

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5393/is-it-possible-to-get-a-random-number-in-the-node-editor

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious, the white noise texture worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most earlier answers to this question, Blender has provided a discontinuous [*White Noise*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/textures/white_noise.html) texture node. Even the smallest change in its 'coordinate' will produce a completely new output in the 0-1 range...

[image]

.. so your seed can simply be an addition to the 'W' input of the 1D version.

[image]

Here, keyed, but could be driven by `#frame`, location, or whatever is appropriate to your case.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Maybe you can leave here this answer, could be useful for other people to see how to use the white noise

Comment: I'd keep the answer ! It perfectly answers the question while mine was more a general one on a broader question. :)