# driver execution in shader nodes

Tags: shader-nodes

I have a driver in my input nodes which works fine. It just outputs a random value.

[image]

But...it will only be executed once.

If i do something like in this screenshot, the x coordinate will be evaluated for every x, right? or am i missing here something?

But my driver value will be executed only once and for all x/y/z values it will be that constant value...can i somehow change this that my driver will be executed for every coordinate as the "less than" node does this?

This is in my driver:

[image]

```
import bpy
import random

# two sample functions
def rand(f,t):
    """ Simple function call:

            invert(val)
    """
    print("executed")
    return random.uniform(f,t)



# Add functions defined in this script into the drivers namespace.
bpy.app.driver_namespace["rand"] = rand
```

Comment: Hello ! Not sure what's in your driver but if it's "just" outputting a random value, you might want to use a White Noise texture https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/213316/86891 with a Map Range node afterwards

Comment: thanks! that was i was looking for. So for me it seems that way, that shader nodes calculates all values once except the ones which has the coordinates as inputs (which makes sense in an optimizing way). So my problem could probably be solved if i had the coordinates as inputs for my driver... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get any value **per** X, the value must be some function **of** X. X is not accessible at the time the driver is evaluated.

For a (discontinuous) random 0-1 per X, you could use X as the coordinate to look up into 1D *White Noise*:

[image]

If you want the value to be random (per X, per Frame), you could use 2D noise:

[image]

Comment: thanks Robin, unfortunately i want to be able to have a random number per texture x coordinate. But i couldn't figure out how to get texture coordinates into my driver...but yes, i understand, this works with white noise, but not with my driver ;)

Comment: but if you know how i get the texture coordinate in my driver i would be very interested....

Comment: @Chris Ahh.. if, by texture coordinate, you mean UV coordinate, plug in 'UV' instead of 'Object'  from the first node. (or, if from a particular non-active UV map then use the _UV Map_ input node).

Comment: sorry, looks like i did not make it clear. Yes i meant UV coordinate, but i meant my driver...how can i get the uv coordinate in my driver?

Comment: @Chris you would have, somehow, to associate something with UV, before render-time. What is your desired end-effect?

Comment: this was just a "i am curious"-question. How i could do that. Thank you!